# tsconfig alias not resolving at paths above baseUri

Tags: typescript, next.js, tsconfig, nrwl-nx

I'm working on a monorepo and have noticed that the tsconfig is not resolving paths that are above the current project.

Here's my project structure:

```
── apps
│   ├── sahl
│   │   ├── index.d.ts
│   │   ├── jest.config.ts
│   │   ├── next-env.d.ts
│   │   ├── next.config.js
│   │   ├── project.json
│   │   ├── public
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   └── tsconfig.spec.json
├── libs
│   └── shared
│       ├── data-access
│       └── zod-types
├── nx.json
├── openapi.json
├── package.json
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── prisma
│   └── schema.prisma
├── tools
│   ├── database
│   ├── tsconfig.tools.json
│   └── zod-to-openapi.ts
└── tsconfig.base.json
```

Ideally, I would like the folders in the "apps" directory to have access to files in the "libs/shared" directory.

At first, I tried including these paths in `tsconfig.base.json`, so they could be extended to apps/sahl's `tsconfig.json`

```json
// ./tsconfig.base.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "@libs/*": ["./libs/**/*.ts"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"],
  "include": ["./libs/shared/data-access/*.ts", "./libs/shared/zod-types/modelSchema/*.ts"],
}
```

But unfortunately after doing some investigation, it turns that the extending promised by tsconfig is in reality an overwriting and not really the merging I expected.

I then tried putting those paths & includes in the child `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "../../",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["./src/styles/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["./src/types/*"],
      "@libs/*": ["../../libs/*"], //not working at build but vscode resolves the paths
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/[*]/*.ts",
    "**/**/*.tsx",
    "../../apps/sahl/.next/types/**/*.ts",
    "../../dist/apps/sahl/.next/types/**/*.ts",
    "../../libs/shared/data-access/**/*.ts", // don't know whether necessary
    "../../libs/shared/zod-types/inputTypeSchemas/*.ts", // don't know whether necessary
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jest.config.ts",
    "src/**/*.{spec,test}.ts"
  ]
}
```

So I'm kind of stuck, I feel like tsc isn't resolving the paths correctly at build time, but it wouldn't explain why vscode and the "dev" part (ie next dev) are still working and recognizing the paths.

If any of you got an idea, I'm more than happy to hear it!

TIA!

## EDIT

Per @jagmitg's recommendations, I've removed baseUri from the child `tsconfig.json` to avoid conflicts:

```json
// apps/sahl/tsconfig.json

{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "../../",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["./src/styles/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["./src/types/*"],
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/[*]/*.ts",
    "**/**/*.tsx",
    "../../apps/sahl/.next/types/**/*.ts",
    "../../dist/apps/sahl/.next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jest.config.ts",
    "src/**/*.{spec,test}.ts"
  ]
}
```

and instead set it in `tsconfig.base.json`:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "@libs/*": ["./libs/**/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"],
  "include": ["./libs/shared/data-access/*.ts", "./libs/shared/zod-types/modelSchema/*.ts"],
}
```

The good news is that now I got a new error message:

```
- info Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.
       
       ./src/app/api/articles/[articleId]/route.ts
       Module not found: Can't resolve '@libs/shared/data-access/articles.data'
```

Maybe a typo or wrong relative path in the includes?

Comment: Your issue might be due to conflicting `baseUrl` and `rootDir` properties in your base and child TypeScript configurations. This might be mucking up your path aliases

Comment: Hmm, looking at the problem, i would suggest trying out `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

tsconfig.base.json - i would suggest setting a baseUrl to the root of your repo which your already doing.

Dont override `baseUrl` in the child config. This will keep the path mapping from the base config valid.

**The base config should look like this**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    // ...
    "paths": {
      "@libs/*": ["./libs/*/*"],
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

**and the child config should look something like this**:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    // No baseUrl override here
    "rootDir": "../../",
    // ...
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./apps/sahl/src/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["./apps/sahl/src/styles/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["./apps/sahl/src/types/*"],
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

**EDIT**:

I would suggest trying out `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to solve this problem.

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./"],
      "alias": {
        "@libs": "./libs"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i've added the suggestions you've made and updated the question with the new error message.

Comment: unfortunately, i feel like the babel config file and plugin are ignored. do i have to reference them somewhere? if yes, how?